# How to validate if after clicking on a link it gets disabled until redirecting to next page?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, intellij-idea, automation

I have to validate if just after clicking on a link the link gets disabled until redirecting to next page in automation testing !!

How to do that in intellij with selenium web driver?

After clicking the link I have put "webaction.enabledElement" in a Boolean method.Thats not working properly. The method supposed to return true but sometimes its returning false

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

- Locate the link element using Selenium WebDriver. You can use various methods such as `findElement(By)` or `findElements(By)` to find the link element based on its attributes (e.g., ID, class, or XPath).
- Click on the link using the `click()` method of the WebElement representing the link.
- Wait for the link to become disabled. You can use explicit or implicit waits to wait for a certain condition to be met. In this case, you can wait until the link becomes disabled by checking its "disabled" attribute or any other indicator of its disabled state.

```java
// Find and click on the link
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Your Link Text"));
link.click();

// Wait for the link to become disabled
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(link, "disabled", "true"));

// Perform validation or assertions here
boolean isLinkDisabled = link.getAttribute("disabled").equals("true");
System.out.println("Is link disabled? " + isLinkDisabled);
```

Comment: In the above solution for the 2nd part you can use the below code as well.

// Perform validation or assertions here boolean
 
isLinkDisabled = link.isEnabled(); 

System.out.println("Is link disabled? " + isLinkDisabled);

Answer (score 0):

### [HTML `disabled` Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp)

The boolean *`disabled`* attribute, when present, makes the element non mutable, non focusable and even can't be submitted with the form. The user can't edit or focus on the control nor its form control descendants as well.

As an example:

```
<form>
    <label for="empDate">Employment Date:</label>
    <input name="empDate" type="date" disabled>
</form>
```

---

### This usecase

So to validate if clicking on a link the link gets disabled until redirecting to next page you can use the following strategy:

```
// find and click on the link
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='link']")).click();
// validate if the link is disabled
try
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='link' and @disabled]"));
    System.out.println("Link was disabled");
}
catch(NoSuchElementException ex)
{
    System.out.println("Link wasn't disabled");
}
```